# Block public IPs routed through reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, fail2ban, owncloud

I have setup my router to port forward traffic from a specific port to a server acting as a reverse proxy.
The server is based on CentOS 7 with Apache 2.4.6. One of my backend servers is also CentOS based and is running an ownCloud instance.

My goal is to block public IPs -using fail2ban- which have multiple bad password attempts (brute force).
For this to happen, I have made sure to passthrough public IPs -using X-Forwarded-For- from the reverse proxy to the ownCloud server. I can also see from the fail2ban status, that indeed public IPs with multiple bad password attempts are blocked.

But... Since the traffic is passing from the reverse proxy (and not directly from the outside world), public IPs, even if blocked on ownCloud server, will continue to have access to the ownCloud server.

Is there any way to block such public IPs in the above setup?
If I am not mistaken, this is possible in NGINX reverse proxies by adding a "set_real_ip_from rev.proxy.ip.add.", but I have not found anything related for apache.

My proxy's configuration, in case it is needed

```
    ServerName my.domain.com

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
    SSLProtocol -All +TLSv1.2
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/chain.pem

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubdomains;"
    Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"

    ProxyPass https://backend.ip/
    ProxyPassReverse https://backend.ip/
```

Comment: Below is not a solution, but a workarkound, for owncloud instances. For anyone interested, there is an ownCloud app that prevents brute forces. https://marketplace.owncloud.com/apps/security